# How can I boost demand for lower density residential areas in Cities: Skylines 2?

Tags: cities-skylines-2

At around level 3 or 4, the only residential zoning that my city demands is high density. But that's unlocked at level 8, so I have to slowly creep my way there (very few people demand other densities), and shops start to close due to lack of customers.

How can I boost demand for lower density residential areas in Cities: Skylines 2?

Comment: you shouldn't be getting demand for high density if you don't even have it unlocked, are you sure the demand isn't for medium density?

Answer (score 2):

High density residential demand can be satisfied by two types of zones:

- EU/NA high density housing, unlocked at milestone 8
- low rent housing, unlocked at milestone 4

Build some low rent housing. After that, the demand for low density housing should rise again.